# Filesystem storage not working in reportportal application

Tags: github, reportportal

I am trying to install report portal application using docker-compose.file with the below command as mentioned in the documentation. I have downloaded docker-compose file from reportportal github repository

> **docker-compose -p reportportal up -d --force-recreate**

volumes details mentioned in docker-compose.yml file like below

> volumes:
>
> > ./data/storage:/var/lib/postgresql/data

The postgres necessary files are getting stored in the current path data/storage local directory.
[image]

Expected behaviour: I wanted to store all those files in the mounted directory which is custom location.

Tried Steps:
So i have changed the volume like below
volumes:
/test-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
And added the lines

> DATASTORE_TYPE: filesystem
> DATASTORE_PATH: /test-data

Problem:
It's not getting stored in the custom location when i executing the command.
Please anyone suggest me to solve this problem.